# Improve this generic jQuery toggle function for tabs, accordions, dialogs, etc

Tags: jquery, toggle

I'm trying to write some simple jQuery that I can use for toggling tab panels, accordion panels, dialogs, etc. I'd like to use the same code for all these cases. Sometimes there will be elements that will not toggle on and off but only perform one of those tasks such as the "X" icon at the top right of a dialog. I'd like to support those as well.

I've created a pen here: http://codepen.io/allthosehumans/pen/jMjmdK

Are there any improvements I could do to make this more elegant?

```
var toggleTriggers = $('[data-trigger]');

var toggleTriggersSetup = function() {
    toggleTriggers.each(function() {

        var targetAction = $(this).attr('data-trigger');
        var targetID = "#" + $(this).attr('data-target');
        var targetElem = $(targetID);

        $(this).click(function() {

            switch (targetAction) {

                case 'toggle':
                    if (targetElem.attr('data-state') == 'active') {
                        targetElem.attr('data-state', 'inactive');
                    } else {
                        targetElem.attr('data-state', 'active');
                    }
                    break;

                case 'activate':
                    if (targetElem.attr('data-state') == 'inactive') {
                        targetElem.attr('data-state', 'active');
                    }
                    break;

                case 'deactivate':
                    if (targetElem.attr('data-state') == 'active') {
                        targetElem.attr('data-state', 'inactive');
                    }
                    break;

            }

            event.preventDefault();

        });
    });
};

toggleTriggersSetup();
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `click` handler can be simplified:

```
var toggleTriggersSetup = function() {
    toggleTriggers.each(function() {

        var targetAction = $(this).attr('data-trigger');
        var targetID = "#" + $(this).attr('data-target');
        var targetElem = $(targetID);

        $(this).click(function() {
            if (targetElem.attr('data-state') == 'active') {
                if (targetAction == 'deactivate' || targetAction == 'toggle') {
                    targetElem.attr('data-state', 'inactive');
                }
            } else {
                if (targetAction == 'activate' || targetAction == 'toggle') {
                    targetElem.attr('data-state', 'active');
                }
            }

            event.preventDefault();
        });
    });
};
```

...and I'd be inclined to read the attributes as of the click rather than earlier, so I'd have the flexibility to change them dynamically if desired. That would also let us get rid of the `each` loop:

```
var toggleTriggersSetup = function() {
    toggleTriggers.click(function() {
        var targetAction = $(this).attr('data-trigger');
        var targetID = "#" + $(this).attr('data-target');
        var targetElem = $(targetID);

        if (targetElem.attr('data-state') == 'active') {
            if (targetAction == 'deactivate' || targetAction == 'toggle') {
                targetElem.attr('data-state', 'inactive');
            }
        } else {
            if (targetAction == 'activate' || targetAction == 'toggle') {
                targetElem.attr('data-state', 'active');
            }
        }

        event.preventDefault();
    });
};
```

...and would arguably make the `toggleTriggersSetup` so trivial it's not worth putting in a function of its own vs. just doing it (but that depends a lot on your code structure).